# Dynamic Scrollbox

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement Dynamic Scrollbox found in http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/dynamic-scrollbox/

but it has a problem of keep getting the same list over and over. so I'm trying to view only the items in my aa.html file.

my aa.html file has the following:

```
<p>Item1</p>
<p>Item2</p>
<p>Item3</p>
<p>Item4</p>
<p>Item5</p>
<p>Item6</p>
<p>Item7</p>
<p>Item8</p>
```

and my implementation script is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Scrolling Dynamic Content box</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
    updatestatus();

});
function updatestatus(){
    //Show number of loaded items
    var totalItems=$('#content p').length;
    $('#status').text('Loaded '+totalItems+' Items');
    $.get('aa.html', function(data) {
        var dom = $('<div/>').append(data);
        var tnoi = dom.find('p').length;
        alert("Total number of items = " + tnoi + ", Items of Current file = " + totalItems);
            if(totalItems < tnoi)
                scrollalert();

});

}
function scrollalert(){
    var scrolltop=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollTop');
    var scrollheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('scrollHeight');
    var windowheight=$('#scrollbox').attr('clientHeight');
    var scrolloffset=20;
    if(scrolltop>=(scrollheight-(windowheight+scrolloffset)))
    {
        //fetch new items
        $('#status').text('Loading more items...');
        $.get('aa.html', '', function(newitems){
            $('#content').append(newitems);
            updatestatus();
        });
    }
    setTimeout('scrollalert();', 1500);
}
</script>

<style type="text/css" >
    #container{ width:400px; margin:0px auto; padding:40px 0; }
    #scrollbox{ width:400px; height:300px;  overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden; border:1px solid #f2f2f2; }
    #container > p{ background:#eee; color:#666; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:0.75em; padding:5px; margin:0; text-align:right;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="scrollbox" >
        <div id="content" >

        </div>
    </div>
    <p><span id="status" ></span></p>
</div>

<hr />
<p>
Demo Provided By: <a href="http://webdeveloperplus.com" title="Web Developer Plus - Ultimate Web Development & Design Resource" >Web
Developer Plus</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you always `$.get()` from the same static HTML URL.  You need to do one of the following:

1. Use a URL that points to some dynamic URL where a server returns successive batches of items on each GET.  (Though that's a bit problematic as it requires the server keeping track of client state.)
2. Keep a counter on the JavaScript side that increments on every `$.get()` using the counter to construct a different URL each time.  For example

   ```
   var batch=0;  //at outer scope, or the top of your namespace
   ...
       batch += 1
       $.get('aa'+batch+'.html', '', function(newitems){
   ```

Then you could have a set of static files: `aa1.html`, `aa2.html`, `aa3.html`, containing successive batches. Or you could have a dynamic script that takes a batch parameter

```
        $.get('aa?batch='+batch, '', function(newitems){
```

---

Update based on comment:

It sounds like you need to just load the entire contents into the scrollbox just once.

What if you simplify your script to something something simple like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $.get('aa.html', function(data) {
            $('<div/>').append(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: but both suggestions will not suite me! as I'm planning to make that single html page available for our admin assistant to insert news.

OK, if this doesn't work, anyone can suggest a similar script? all what I need is to create two scrollboxes in one page, each box will read new items from a separate HTML file. any alternative method (HTML, Java, PHP, Flash ... ) is accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Eamonn. I ended up creating a container with table inside, and I will ask the assistant to manually edit the table to add new items (of course using cms) .. so thanks for trying .. I will mark your response as answer.